# Instabot is not working with flask web app

Tags: python, flask, postman, flask-restful

I am trying to use [instabot](https://github.com/ohld/igbot) for logging into my account and fetching the followers list of user. It is working fine without using flask but when I try to run the same bot with flask routes, it throws me some error

```
import json
from logging import error
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, abort
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    try:
        data = request.json
        print(data['userName'])
        usernameval = data['userName']
        passwordval = data['password']
        bot.login(username=usernameval,password=passwordval)
        bot.send_message("Hi",["highoncarb"])
        response = {'success': True}   
    except Exception as error:
        response = {'success': False}
    finally:
        return response
```

this is my console giving :

```
2021-05-29 20:03:08,275 - INFO - Not yet logged in starting: PRE-LOGIN FLOW!
2021-05-29 20:03:58,445 - INFO - Logged-in successfully as 'karter19x'!
2021-05-29 20:03:58,446 - INFO - LOGIN FLOW! Just logged-in: True
192.168.43.102 - - [29/May/2021 20:04:19] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I am sending the request using Postman desktop agent
[image: Postman]

Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

you are not return anything because of the exception, thus the 500 error occurs. try your function like this:

```
    try:
        data = request.json
        print(data['userName'])
        usernameval = data['userName']
        passwordval = data['password']
        # loginstatus = bot.login(username="",password="")
        bot.login(username=usernameval,password=passwordval)
        # print(loginstatus)
        response = {'success': True, 'message': "Login success..!"}
        print(response)
    except Exception as error:
        response = {'success': error, 'message': "Try Again..!"}

    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: I edited the code as you told but this time it is giving me {'success': error, 'message': "Try Again..!"} error output, Why I couldn't be able to login with the bot ?

Comment: I edited my question, bot is not able to login if used under the flask app decorator

Comment: Try to create a Bot object inside your function. I'm guessing here, but I think this might be the problem here why you're not able to login

Comment: what type of error are you getting when you print out the error in the catch?
`response = {'success': False, 'message': error}`

Comment: Signal thread can only be in main function, something like that

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
bot.login(username='username',password='password',is_threaded=True)
```

you are getting this error because your are running both flask and instabot in a single thread.